# Encode Store Data as JSON String in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to make a simple Sencha Touch App that submits a form with attached images, and stores the data in a remote MySQL database via PHP.

The user-inserted images are stored in a data store.

When the user clicks the submit button, I would like all the data in the store to be encoded into a JSON string which I can easily send to my database.

Is there any way to do this in Sencha Touch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch has the JSON lib included, you can encode in the following manner:

```
Ext.util.JSON.encode(formDataArray)
```

Also have a look at the Sencha Touch API Docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.JSON which references http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

You can encode image to [Base64](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?126882-Base64-Encoder) string and when attached to your form you can store base64 string value in a [hidden field](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Hidden) in your form.

When user clicks submit button you retrieve values in your form using **activePanel.getValues(false)**.This gives you JSON presentation of components you used in your form and their values.